# Why doesn't my git ignore file match xcuserdata?

Tags: gitignore

My `~/.config/git/ignore` file includes:

```
xcuserdata/**
```

I just checked out a new project from Bitbucket, opened it in Xcode, and ran `git status`, and it shows:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Project Name.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
```

Why isn't the ignore file matching this directory?

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to exclude a folder, you don't need '`**`'

```
# The trailing slash is enough
xcuserdata/
```

Second, check if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set.
The default path for a global gitignore is indeed (if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty) `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`

If nothing works, directly set it through:

```
git config --global core.excludesFile /path/to/global/ignore/file
```

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141396/discussion-between-vaddadi-kartick-and-vonc), the [OP Vaddadi Kartick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297868/vaddadi-kartick) has remove any .git/info/exclude (which had a `xcuserdata` in it, without trailing slash).
Vaddadi kept `~/.config/git/ignore` with `xcuserdata/`, and the status now ignores that folder.

Comment: $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set, and xcuserdata still shows as an untracked file. How do I fix this?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick do you have any tracked file in `xcuserdata`? Try a `git rm --cached "Flashed Camera.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/"`

Comment: It says: fatal: pathspec <path> did not match any files. I confirmed on the Bitbucket web UI, and xcuserdata isn't tracked.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick Can you try and clone that repo again, to see if the error persists?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick can you do in that local repo a `git check-ignore -v project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata` to see if any ignore rule is supposed to happen?

Comment: .git/info/exclude:7:xcuserdata project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata

Comment: @VaddadiKartick Strange, there should be a trailing / to indicate a folder. And this is not your .gitignore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141396/discussion-between-vaddadi-kartick-and-vonc).

Comment: @VaddadiKartick I have to go to work, I will follow the discussion on my phone

Comment: You can respond to my chat comments at your convenience. Okay for me to type my comments in the chat room?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick I have edited the answer to include the conclusion of this discussion. Let me know if I have misinterpreted anything.